# Getting only external identifiers from Wikidata SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, wikidata-api

I am trying to create a SPARQL query that will retrive only the external identifiers for a record.  Basically, I want to retrieve the items listed under the "Identifers" section on one of the dedicated pages, e.g. https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q112133367 includes the IMDB movie ID and the Rotten Tomatoes ID for the film.

I am able to get all the available properties for an item (I know the item's Wikidata ID).  This is something like `SELECT * FROM wikidata WHERE id='Q112133367'`:

```
SELECT ?value ?valueLabel ?prop ?propLabel {
    wd:Q112133367 ?prop ?value .
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

I've tried using the `VALUES` syntax, which I think is equivalent in this case (?):

```
SELECT ?item ?value ?valueLabel ?prop ?propLabel ?p2 ?p2Label {
  VALUES (?item) {(wd:Q112133367)}
  ?item ?prop ?value .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

But so far I have been unable to limit the properties returned to only ones that are External Identifiers.  This is what I tried, but this results in "No matching records found":

```
SELECT ?item ?value ?valueLabel ?prop ?propLabel ?p2 ?p2Label {
  VALUES (?item) {(wd:Q112133367)}
  ?item ?prop ?value .
  ?prop wikibase:propertyType wikibase:ExternalId .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

Comment: `SELECT ?item ?value ?valueLabel ?prop ?propLabel ?p2 ?p2Label {
  VALUES (?item) {(wd:Q112133367)}
  ?item ?a ?value .
  ?prop wikibase:propertyType wikibase:ExternalId .
  ?prop wikibase:directClaim ?a .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick!  If you want to post this as an answer, then it can be marked as a solution.